# How to wget a file at a moving adress?

Tags: bash, wget

I am trying to download a PDF file from a website, I know the name of the file, e.g. **foo.pdf**, but It's location changes every few weeks:

e.g.
**www.server.com/media/123456/foo.pdf**
changes into
**www.server.com/media/245415/foo.pdf**

The number is always a six-figure number, so I tried using a bash script to go through all 10 million of them, but that obviously takes a lot of time:

```
i=0
until [ "$RC" == "0" ] || [ $i == 1000000 ]
do
  b=$(printf %06d $i)
  wget -q http://www.server.com/media/${b}/foo.pdf -O bar.pdf
  export RC=$?
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

For wrong addresses I just get 404 errors.
I tested it around the currently correct address and it works.

Does anyone know a faster way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that page is linked form anywhere else, then you can get the link from there, and just get the file. If it's not, you are probably out of luck.

Note that most servers would consider trying to hit the webserver 1,000,000 times abuse, and would ban your IP for even trying.

Comment: thanks :)
the page is linked, and I usually download the file manually using firefox, do you know is there a way to do it automatically with wget?

Comment: You can probably parse the page and look for a html match of the link via regex.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the values from time to time and work out if they're algorithmic or not.  As zigdon said above though, if you have the source for the link, just wget that first, and follow the link to the PDF.